# How to pivot a data frame with two columns and several observations for each group in R?

Tags: r, pivot, transform, reshape

It looks like it could be easily done using `pivot_wider()`, however this function seems to only work where information is grouped by more than one variable. Here's my data frame:

```
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(group = c(rep(c(1:3), each=3)),
                value = sample(10:20, 9, replace = T))
  group value
1     1    14
2     1    14
3     1    19
4     2    15
5     2    19
6     2    16
7     3    18
8     3    14
9     3    14
```

And the desired output is:

```
1  2  3
14 15 18
14 19 14
19 16 14
```

How would you do it?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I just realised that columns can't be named after numbers. So the column names could be something like: C1, C2, C3.

Answer (score 3):

Try `unstack` like below

```
unstack(rev(df))
```

which gives

```
  X1 X2 X3
1 18 10 20
2 13 11 11
3 16 16 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `tidyverse`, you need to add a dummy column to tell `pivot_wider` which rows to use...

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%       #adds id row numbers for each group
  pivot_wider(names_from = group) %>% 
  select(-id)                         #remove them again

# A tibble: 3 x 3
    `1`   `2`   `3`
  <int> <int> <int>
1    14    15    18
2    14    19    14
3    19    16    14
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), rowid(group) ~ paste0("C", group))[, group := NULL][]
```

-output

```
#   C1 C2 C3
#1: 18 10 20
#2: 13 11 11
#3: 16 16 20
```